# Using $.ajax inside .ajaxStart()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting some data from API and data is large. I am getting this data with an AJAX call.

My problem is that I want to show a loader image until all data has been fetched. In my AJAX success function I hide my loader image.

This does not solve my problem: the image is hidden but the data is still being fetched.

I searched on google and found `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`, but `.ajaxStart()` does not have more information how to use AJAX inside it.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $.ajax(); // my ajax call
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    image.hide(); // hide my image
 });
```

But this not solve my problem. Can someone tell me about it how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Write your `$.ajax();` separately and keep the below as a global.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('img').show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('img').hide();
});
```

Incase still you find any difficult then try to do this in **`callbacks`**.

```
$.ajax({
   // you ajax attributes 
   beforeSend: function(){
     $("img").show();
   },   
   success: function(data) {
     //handle the data that is being fetched
     $("img").hide();
   },
   error: function(error) {
     //handle the error
     $("img").hide();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly it's possible that it's not quite clear to you what `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxStop()` are for.

If you want to show a loader image while a *single* Ajax call is processing, you can do this:

```
$('#loader').show();  // assuming the loader is e.g. <div id="loader">loading</div>

$.ajax( ... )         // your ajax call
    .done( function() {
        // when it's finished hide the loader
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
```

If you want to show the loader for *every* Ajax call, use `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxStop()`:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart( function() {
    $('#loader').show();
}).ajaxStop( function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: Now I understand the behavior of `$.ajaxStart()` and  `$.ajaxStop()` these two will run ajax call will go from .ajax

Comment: yes definitely I want to show loader on every Ajax call So now I should use  `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxStop()` after `$.ajax();` right?

Comment: No, before. They set the event, you don't have to wrap individual ajax calls with them.